# manually build a linear regression in sklearn without using fit?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

Is it possible to build a LinearRegression in sklearn by passing in the intercept and coefficents instead of using `.fit`?

Comment: "Is there any way" is a non-issue for Stack Overflow. Since you're on a general-purpose computer that is barely short of a Turing machine, the answer is almost always "yes". The follow-up question, "How do I do it?", is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You can manually build a fit method working with custom inputs, but you wouldn't use "fit" or "sklearn" as far as I understand what you mean. You can do an online search and you will find many useful sites that can help you do it.

Comment: Did you try assigning to `model.coef_` and `model.intercept_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested by Mustafa Aydin in its comment, you can simply assign coefficient and intercept to scikit-learn LinearRegression.

The following snippet is modeling the function `y = 10 + x*5`.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

l = LinearRegression()
l.coef_ = np.array([5])
l.intercept_ = np.array([10])
l.predict([[3]])
```

**NOTES**: If you are not using scikit-learn to fit your linear regression, you can simply use numpy, which might be more performant.